# Building A Voltage Threshold Indicator with Wide Voltage Window (0-600V)

Tags: voltage-measurement, zener

**Background:**

I'm from A Formula SAE Team designing a building a EV to Compete in an FSAE Competition.

**Situation:**

We construct an Accumulator that houses the batteries and related components. 
This has to have an indicator that indicates when the Vehicle side of the Isolation Relays has a DC Voltage of above 60V.

That is to say when the exposed +/- terminals of the accumulator have a VDC of 60V or higher an indicator is lit.

**Idea:**

Basic 60V Zener Diode inline with appropriate resistor for current limit.

i.e *1N5264B-TP Zener Diode*

**Problem:**

how do I deal with such a wide voltage window?

I'm having trouble working out from the diode datasheets whether or not applying up to 600V is possible, obviously the maximum voltage is not unlimited but it's hard to find out what the window actually is.

Note: the circuit may not see up to 600V, it's just that according to FSAE-EV Rules we are not allowed a tractive voltage above 600V, so any circuit that can work with 60V-600V will suit us regardless of what the end voltage may be.

We expect the actual voltage to be somewhere around the 450-500V +/- 50V

Comment: I don't understand how you are planning on connecting the zener as an indicator. The zener emits smoke when the voltage is above 60? :P Could you please draw the design using the integrated schematic editor?

Comment: Do you want the indicator powered from the same voltage that you're indicating? If not, a simple resistor divider can drop your 60-600V into something more manageable like 1-10V.

Comment: And what sort of indicator - LED, filament lamp?

Comment: @pipe, the zener was just used as a 'conduct above 60V' or don't conduct below it, followed by a resistor to an appropriate LED.

Comment: no the indicator does not have to be powered from the same voltage, it just has to be indicative of it's existence. 

I initially dismissed the divider due to the potential power dissipation of dropping 500+ volts, but apparently not such a bad idea.

as for indicator type, it doesn't matter but LED would likely be the best solution give low power consumption.

Comment: you say teh indicator does not have to be powered by the same voltage? What happens if the auxiliary voltage fails when the HV supply is up? You have a dangerous supply, and no indication.

Comment: oh i read it as it doesn't have to be powered directly AT 600V or whatever.

yes you are correct, the indicator would be powered by that same voltage. the rules actually state 
"EV3.3.10 The voltage being present at the connectors must directly control the indicator using hard wired 
electronics (no software control is permitted). Activating the indicator with the control signal which
closes the AIRs is not sufficient."

which to me reads as logically control, but I suspect there is another rule that allows them to shoot down any system that has an as you said, dangerous supply solution

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer is to use a resistor divider to scale down the voltage, then compare that to a proportionally lower threshold voltage.

You could use something like a TL431 as the threshold detector, or a comparator that compares to a threshold divided down from a regulated supply, or various other things.

Let's say you have a comparator that runs from 5 V.  The maximum of 600 V in should then result in about 5 V out after the divider.  Let's pick 2 MΩ for the top resistor.  That means the bottom resistor should be 16.8 kΩ.  The output signal from the divider will be the input voltage divided by 120.

60 V in will therefore yield 500 mV out of the divider.  The output of the divider goes into one input of a comparator, and a 500 mV reference voltage into the other.

Note that you have to consider the power dissipation of the top resistor of the divider.  Worst case, it will have 595 V across it.  That means this 2 MΩ resistor will dissipate 180 mW.  It should therefore be at least ¼ W resistor.  It also needs to be rated to withstand 600 V.

Sometimes in cases like this it's easier to put multiple smaller resistors in series, both for the lower power dissipation and voltage for each individual resistor.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, especially since you need it all powered from the high voltage supply, it may be simpler to go old-tech and use a [60V neon bulb](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/optoelectronics/lamps-incandescents-neons/101?k=neon%20bulb&k=&pkeyword=neon%20bulb&pv63=462&FV=ffe00065&mnonly=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&quantity=0&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) with a suitable resistor or current limiter.

[image]

These lamps have that interesting turn on threshold that you are looking for.

[image]

Depending on how bright you want it, larger neons will require more power dissipation in the resistor or current limiter.

Potential wide supply voltage driver circuit..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwXXl8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

NOTE: If you use the [shown MOSFET](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/group1/dc/96/f3/cc/62/ab/4b/9e/CD00003701/files/CD00003701.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003701.pdf) the gate voltage limiting zener diode is built in.